# Bootstrap Tooltip not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've passed all the Stack Overflow, tried literally anything.
The tooltip doesn't working.
Can you please help me !!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" rel="tooltip" title="hello" data-placement="bottom">Hello World</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Include bootstrap.js file after jquery.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on **dfsq**'s comment - Add the jQuery js file before the bootstrap js file.

```
<script src="[jQuery JavaScript file]"></script>
<script src="[Bootstrap JavaScript file]"></script>
```

The Bootstrap JS file is based on jQuery.
Therefore in order to make sure everything works - this is the order to add the script tag calls in the `<head>` tag.